# Is there any way to not present errors in the console performing ocr.Read(input)

Tags: c#, ocr, tesseract

I am trying to read numbers and letters from an image in a Console Application, so far so good.
But when the image doesn't have any letters or numbers it shows an error message in the Console when performing the ocr.Read(Input):
[image]

My question is, Is there a way to prevent the error to show in the console?
Code below:

```cs
var ocr = new IronTesseract();           
using (var input = new OcrInput(imgLocation))
{
    var result = ocr.Read(input);
}
```

Comment: Try something like `ocr.Configuration.Logging.Mode = Tesseract.LoggingMode.None;`

Comment: doesnt exist .Logging

Answer (score 0):

It helps to disable the error output of the console with `Console.SetError(TextWriter.Null);`. This disables many error messages, but unfortunately not all of them. A workaround is print them in a different color.

```cs
Console.SetError(TextWriter.Null);
Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;

var ocr = new IronTesseract();
using (var input = new OcrInput(imgLocation))
{
    var result = ocr.Read(input);

    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
    Console.WriteLine(result.Text);
}
```

I also tried to temporarily set the Console's `Out` to `TextWriter.Null`, but this does not help. Obviously resets the output to the standard output in some cases.